# Обработка 1000 асинхронных POST-запросов в секунду в Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, асинхронность, axios

Я столкнулся с проблемой в моем боте Telegram на Node.js. Мой сервер отправляет  приблизительно 1000 запросов в секунду в телеграмм сервер. Учитывая репутацию Node.js в быстрой обработке запросов, я пользуюсь асинхронной функцией для отправки запросов.
И еще настроил cronjob для периодической проверки результата getConnectionCount каждые 2 секунды. В целом, эта функция возвращает N1->0, что указывает на то, что в данный момент 0 не законченных запросов. Однако в периоды особенно высокой нагрузки я заметил, что getConnectionCount возвращает необычно высокие результаты, например:

> 14.03 05:07:41 N95->1431
>
> 14.03 05:07:43 N81->1440
>
> 14.03 05:07:45 N99->1976
>
> 14.03 05:07:47 N96->1437
>
> 14.03 05:07:49 N100->1979
>
> 14.03 05:07:51 N84->1455
>
> 14.03 05:07:53 N101->1977
>
> 14.03 05:07:55 N101->1992

Сначала подозревал, что эти пики связаны с проблемами задержки на сервере Telegram. Однако после дальнейшего исследования я обнаружил, что отправка curl-запросов (например, sendMessage) на сервер Telegram непосредственно с того же сервера дает постоянно быстрые ответы. То есть получается в node почему то запросы висят просто так и не выполняются.

Интересно, что быстрое решение этой проблемы заключается в простом перезапуске приложения Node.js с использованием pm2 restart app. После перезапуска бот восстанавливает нормальную работу, и getConnectionCount возвращает опять N1->0 целый день. И где-то через день опять это повторяется.

Я немного озадачен тем, почему эти запросы застревают после некоторого времени, несмотря на то, что сервер способен обрабатывать ту же самую нагрузку запросов. Любые идеи или предложения о том, что может вызывать эту проблему были бы очень полезны.

Код моего приложения Node.js:

```
var express = require('express');
const axios = require("axios");
const Noderavel = require("@movilizame/noderavel");
const nodelaravel = require("node-laravel-queue");
const {uuid} = require("node-laravel-queue/lib/tools");
const redis = require("redis");
const {serialize} = require("php-serialize");
var app = express();

app.use(express.json({limit: '100mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '100mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000}));

const nocache = require('nocache');
const processId = process.pid;

app.use(nocache());

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});

let connectionCount = 0;
let pendingCount = 0;

// Middleware to track connections
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    connectionCount++;

    res.on('finish', () => {
        connectionCount--;
    });

    next();
});

app.get("/getConnectionCount", function (req, res) {
    res.send(connectionCount.toString() + "->" + pendingCount.toString());
});

async function sendPostRequest(url, postData) {
    try {
        pendingCount++;

        // Make the POST request using axios
        const response = await axios.post(url, postData);

        pendingCount--;

        return response.data;
        // console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        pendingCount--;

        return error.response ? error.response.data : error.message;
    }
}

app.post('/sendRequest/:bot_token', async function (req, res) {
    // for (let index = 0; index < 1e7; index++);

    let bot_token = req.params['bot_token'];

    const postData = req.body;

    let method = postData.method;
    let data = postData.data;
    let get_result = parseInt(postData.get_result);

    let url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + bot_token + "/" + method;

    if (get_result == 1) {
        res.send(await sendPostRequest(url, data));
        return;
    }

    sendPostRequest(url, data);
    res.send("1");
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log(`Server Started in process ${processId}`);
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
server.keepAliveTimeout = 65000; // Ensure all inactive connections are terminated by the ALB, by setting this a few seconds higher than the ALB idle timeout
server.headersTimeout = 66000; // Ensure the headersTimeout is set higher than the keepAliveTimeout due to this nodejs regression bug: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27363
server.setTimeout(10000);
```

Comment: Похоже но то, что нет ответа и запрос "висит" на ожидании. Попробуйте сбрасывать соединение через N секунд. Еще уберите переменные из запросов. Возможно сбор мусора так влияет, если нода подвисает, зачищая кучу старых данных

Comment: Оперативная память "очень" свободная, то есть утечка памяти нету вроде. Еще один странный момент: getConnectionCount иногда возвращает 5->0. То есть 5 соединений 0 не выполненных запросов. Как такое может быть если этот скрипт на локале и getConnectionCount вызывается только 1 cronom, остальное 4 соединения открыты, но 0 запросов выполняют. Почему соединение не закрыто если пост запрос уже выполнен

Comment: Вопрос не в утечке памяти, а в вычищении памяти сборщиком мусора. Создали за секунду 1000 объектов, ему придется эту 1000 удалять. Почему 4 соединения, а 0 запросов - допустим, 2 только установили соединение и запрос еще не вызывался, а остальные 2 уже отработали, но сессию не разорвали пока.

Comment: И еще на счет большого количества вызовов... Увидел, что у вас есть вызов `sendPostRequest(url, data);` без await при `get_result != 1`. Возможно это они. Сессия разрывается, а вызов продолжает выполняться

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вам предложил, на время отладки(а может понравится и оставить на постоянку), дополнить код сбором более детальной информации о происходящем у вас внутри.

Вот мое предложение по дополнению и оптимизации(не изменяемые функции и методы не включены)

```js
// Текущие запросы
const requests = {
    pendingCount: 0
}
// ошибки вызова
const errorRequests = {
    requestErrors: 0
}
// Количество запросов(уникальный ключ)
let requestNum = 0;

app.get("/getConnectionCount", function (req, res) {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({
        connected: connectionCount, // Количество соединений
        pending: requests.pendingCount, // Количество текущих запросов
        requestCNT: requestNum, // Сколько запросов выполнено
        activeRequests: requests, // Список запросов с параметрами
        errorsList: errorRequests, // список ошибок вызовов
    }));
});

async function sendPostRequest(url, postData, reqType, reqNum) {
    try {
        // Увеличили счетчик
        requests.pendingCount++;
        // Записываем параметры вызова
        requests[reqNum] = {
            start: new Date(), // Время вызова
            url, // Адрес
            postData, // Параметры запроса
            reqType // Тип запроса(get_result == 1 ?)
        }
        return await axios.post(url, postData).then(res => res.data);
    } catch (error) {
        // Сохраняем ошибку
        errorRequests[reqNum] = { ...requests[reqNum] }
        errorRequests[reqNum].errorTime = new Date();
        errorRequests[reqNum].errorText = error;
        errorRequests.requestErrors++;
        return error.response ? error.response.data : error.message;
    } finally {
        // В конце уменьшаем счетчик вызовов
        requests.pendingCount--;
        // Удаляем ключ
        delete requests[reqNum];
    }
}

app.post('/sendRequest/:bot_token', async function (req, res) {
    requestNum++;
    let url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + req.params['bot_token'] + "/" + req.body.method;

    if (parseInt(req.body.get_result) === 1) {
        res.send(await sendPostRequest(url, req.body.data, 1, requestNum));
    } else {
        sendPostRequest(url, req.body.data, 0, requestNum);
        res.send("1");
    }
});
```

Основные моменты:

- Добавлен объект `requests`, которых хранит в себе все параметры вызова. При завершении вызова, ключ удаляется
- Если произошла ошибка, запись переносится в объект `errorRequests` с временем ошибки и ее текстом
- Добавлены 2 новых параметра в функцию `sendPostRequest`, что бы было понятно, откуда вызывалось
- Убраны лишние переменные, что бы сборщик мусора тратил меньше времени на свою работу

Если по результатам исследований выяснится, что есть "подвисшие запросы", то, в зависимости от версии node, можно добавить [принудительное прерывание запроса axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation)